# round robin image rotation what is the best way to do in opencv

Tags: wpf, opencv, image-processing, gdi+

I want to do a round robin image rotation as shown below. [image]

The x vertical line from the start of image is removed and added to the end of image.

What is the best way to do this in OpenCV, GDI++ and WPF? I need a solution for each of these platform but they could be implemented differently.

I need to implement it in a function with the following signature(for opencv)

```
  Mat CircShift(Mat inputImage, int PixelInXdirectionToShift);
```

I know how can I do this by manipulating pixels, but I am looking for a solution that do this very fast when pixel manipulation is not that fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Mat outImg(inputImg.size(),inputImg.type());
inputImg(Rect(0, 0, shiftX, height)).copyTo(outImg(Rect(width-shiftX, 0, shiftX, height)));
inputImg(Rect(shiftX, 0, width-shiftX, height)).copyTo(outImg(Rect(0, 0, width-shiftX, height)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For OpenCV take a look at [remap](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html).

EDIT:
Easy/Quick creation of map (using vector):

```
//Create vector of what the rows/cols look like
std::vector<int> t_X,t_Y;
for (int i = 0; i < img.cols(); i++) t_X.push_back(i);
for (int i = 0; i < img.rows(); i++) t_Y.push_back(i);

//circular shift t_X vector
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
int zeroPixel = 50; //This x-pixel to bring to 0 (shifting to the left)

it = std::find(t_X.begin(), t_X.end(), zeroPixel);
std::rotate(t_X.begin(), it, t_X.end());

//Create Maps
 //Turn vectors in cv::Mat
 cv::Mat xRange = cv::Mat(t_X);
 cv::Mat yRange = cv::Mat(t_Y);
 //Maps
 cv::Mat xMap;
 cv::Mat yMap;

 cv::repeat(xRange.reshape(1,1), yRange.total(), 1, xMap);
 cv::repeat(yRange.reshape(1,1).t(), 1, xRange.total(), yMap);
```

You could also use ROIs

```
int zeroPixel = 50;
cv::Mat newMat;
cv::Mat rightHalf = img(cv::Rect(0,0,zeroPixel,img.rows()));
cv::Mat leftHalf = img(cv::Rect(0,zeroPixel+1,img.cols()-zeroPixel-1,img.rows());
cv::hconcat(leftHalf , rightHalf , newMat);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I think it is not fast as I need to create the map first and then do the shift. Creating the map is slow and if I do this by manipulating pixels, probably I am getting the same overhead as creating a map.

Comment: You will have to shift the pixels somehow, you could try and do it by manually moving the pixels around, or trying to shift the array data itself. By that time, you would have probably created a simplified version of remap. I added a simple and quick way of created a shifted map to my answer. Since you are just shifting along columns you can use INTER_NEAREST as the interpolation method without loosing image quality and it will do that remapping quickly.

Comment: Okay I don't know why I'm so intrigued by this problem, but I added another way to do it using ROIs (essentially cut and paste), could be faster.