# Translate image instead of subimage copy

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

Imagine you have an large picture, let's say about 10000px x 3000px and you like to translate it left on the x axis and in a very *efficient* way. So no AffineTransform or smth like that is wanted. If possible, the part moved out on the left side should be appended on the right side, so a kind of turn around would be very cool.

What you have on hand are: Java 7, OpenCV.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956027/round-robin-image-rotation-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-in-opencv) you can see how it can be done with OpenCV in C++. You just need to translate it to Java:

```
// C++:
Mat outImg(inputImg.size(),inputImg.type());
inputImg(Rect(0, 0, shiftX, height)).copyTo(outImg(Rect(width-shiftX, 0, shiftX, height)));
```

Becomes something like:

```
Mat outImg = new Mat(inputImg.size(),inputImg.type());
inputImg.submat(new Rect(0, 0, shiftX, height)).copyTo(outImg.submat(new Rect(width-shiftX, 0, shiftX, height)));
```

Although this one liner is not very readable ;)