# round robin image rotation what is the best way to do in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I am looking to find the best way to do this in wpf. I already asked this question and got an answer which implement it in opencv. [round robin image rotation what is the best way to do in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956027/round-robin-image-rotation-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-in-opencv)

What is the best way to do this in wpf.
Apparently I can create a writableBitmap and copy the pixels manually, but I don't think it is the best way to do this.

## Edit 1

To clarify what I am asking: I like to implement the same algorithm that suggested in this SO question ([round robin image rotation what is the best way to do in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956027/round-robin-image-rotation-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-in-opencv)) using WPF.

What is the best way to do this in WPF which is efficient (memory and speed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an **ImageBrush** to draw on a rectangle and adjust the **ViewPort** property of the brush to slide the image. If you wanted to do an animation with this, here is a sample XAML in WPF which uses animation to automatically adjust the viewport property of the brush and perform a slide animation. Hope this is helpful.

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush x:Name="MyBrush" Viewport="0,0,1,1" TileMode="Tile">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="lSXfX.png" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <RectAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyBrush" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Viewport"
                            From="0 0 1 1" To="1 0 1 1" Duration="0:0:10"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I control the RectAnimation from code behind? I want to move the view port a bit to left or right based on user input.

Comment: yes you can... comment the Rectangle.Triggers from the xaml, you can change MyBrush.Viewport from the code behind.