# Is there a way to increase the speed of this pices of code (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, image-processing

I have this code that would do round robin rotation of an image (as explained in this post [round robin image rotation what is the best way to do in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956027/round-robin-image-rotation-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-in-opencv))

The code that I have for c# is as follow:

```
private BitmapSource RoundRobinImage(BitmapSource inputImage, int noOfPixel)
    {
        var imageHeight = (int)inputImage.Height;
        var imageWidth = (int)inputImage.Width;
        var outputBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(inputImage);
        int sect1Width = (noOfPixel > 0) ? noOfPixel : imageWidth + noOfPixel;
        int sect2Width = imageWidth - sect1Width;
        int bytesPerPixel = (inputImage.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
        {
            var sourceRect1 = new Int32Rect(0, 0, sect1Width, imageHeight);
            int stride1 = bytesPerPixel * sect1Width;
            var pixelBuffer1 = new byte[stride1 * imageHeight];
            inputImage.CopyPixels(sourceRect1, pixelBuffer1, stride1, 0);

            sourceRect1.X = sect2Width;
            sourceRect1.Y = 0;
            outputBitmap.WritePixels(sourceRect1, pixelBuffer1, stride1, 0);
        }
        {
            var sourceRect2 = new Int32Rect(sect1Width, 0, sect2Width, imageHeight);
            int stride2 = bytesPerPixel * sect2Width;
            var pixelBuffer2 = new byte[stride2 * imageHeight];
            inputImage.CopyPixels(sourceRect2, pixelBuffer2, stride2, 0);

            sourceRect2.X = 0;
            sourceRect2.Y = 0;
            outputBitmap.WritePixels(sourceRect2, pixelBuffer2, stride2, 0);
        }

        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

The code works, but it is not fast. Is there any way to improve its performance and increate its speed?

I am using wpf and .net 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tons of:

- Get all pixels into an array, use unsafe code and a pointer to manipulate them.
- If that is WPF, why doing hat per se? Why not just use a transform to render the image turned? This handles it on the graphics card.
- Use Direct3d if you want to get extreme, render from a source to a target.

A lot deends on usage scenario. I Would generally assume that unless you save the turned image the whole turning is not smart because WPF can do that - as I said - with transforms.

Comment: Thanks. I need to save the transformed image to file. Can I do this with wpf transforms? Any lead to where can I read /find more information on how implement this?

Comment: Google? http://blog.biophysengr.net/2011/11/rapid-bitmap-access-using-unsafe-code.html "Rapid Bitmap Access using "Unsafe" Code (Pointers) in C#" for example. It deals explicitly with his - the perforamnce differences are brutal. This is one of the use cases where the array boundary checks come back and KILL you performance wise.

Comment: Thanks. This is for using unsafe code, is there any example on using wpf transform? if I use wpf transform, can I save image into a file? How can I implement round robin with wpf transform?

Comment: I think you can. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/18/wpf-xaml-saving-a-window-or-canvas-as-a-png-bitmap.aspx - you really do not like doing any work yourself, or? I just found that by googling "wpf save control to bitmap".

Comment: Thanks for your comment and also kind reminder that I should do my homework:). I am wondering if I can implement this as a transform or a combination of transforms? I am Googling it, but if you have any idea that could help me find it quickly, it is very appreciating.

Comment: @mans: You also forget, what you need accept the answers.